# Authentication options for Java web application

Tags: java, tomcat, authentication, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I have a question about integrating authentication into my web application.

First let me give the relevant technology background of my web application -

1. Application/Web Server - Tomcat 8.5
2. Underlying OS - CentOS 7.x 64-bit
3. Programming technology - Java Servlets 3.1
4. JDK version - 1.8
5. UI technology - Browser based; Developed using Angular2/Javascript/HTML/CSS
6. Web application users - Targeted at enterprise users

As of now, there isn't an authentication system built into the web application. However as I  build this web application, I need to include an authentication module.

My main points to consider as I decide on authentication system/technology are -

1. I preferably do not want my application to deal with the storage and protection (on disk) of the user credentials
2. I preferably do not want my application to deal with enforcing password complexity, history, expiration policies etc.

My application will have to provide for -

1. A login page to allow the user to login
2. A change password page
3. A create user page

Based on the above, I am currently thinking of deploying a Windows Server 2016 instance as the Active Directory(AD) server that will hold the credentials for the application users. Note that at this point, this Windows server is not planned to be shared with any other application to support a single sign-on experience across applications.

I am planning to configure my Tomcat server with a JNDI realm to authenticate users (against the AD) and then use some kind of Java AD library that will allow me to create an user and change a user's password in AD via my application's create user and change password page.

My application will support its own custom roles and authorization constraints so i am not looking to use AD's group membership for authorization within the web application.

**My questions are -**

1. With the above setup, are there any reference authentication systems/libraries/modules that might be better suited (than AD) to integrate within my web application?
2. If I go with the above Windows AD server approach then are there any Java (inbuilt or community developed) AD libraries that allow for creating an user in AD, changing user password in AD etc. I have used the JNDI realm before so I am sure that it can be used to authenticate the incoming user against AD

I am not an expert in Spring Security and my web application does not currently use Spring Security but I am open to using it if Spring Security includes a solution to my problem described above.

I am also not worried about supporting single sign-on as such and its totally fine in my scenario if the application users have a separate login for my application.

Since my web application is targeted at enterprise users, I don't want to leverage Facebook authentication. As much as possible I want to ensure that the credentials are maintained in a server within the deployment infrastructure rather than the credentials being hosted and maintained by a 3rd party service

Thank you for your help and suggestions

Comment: Suppose you can try with [waffle](https://github.com/Waffle/waffle) that supports spring security integration.

Comment: Jason web tokens